# Ajax not reciving data. Symfony2

Tags: ajax, symfony

The idea is when i click on a button it calls sendeRequest() and the controller receives the petition. But I'm not receiving anything.

I wan't to send a request to the controller. (I have set a redirection in the controller, to check that I'm receiving the data). I've tried doing:

```
function sendRequest(){ 
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:  "{{ path('login') }}" ,
   cache: "false",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(result){ $("div#box").append(result);}
 }); 
}
```

And in the controller

```
$request = $this->getRequest();   
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){    
         return $this->render('mainBundle:Register:register.html.twig');
}
```

I'm using jquery 1.7.2

Comment: What does firebug/chrome debugger tell you?

Comment: +1 to Sgoettschkes, if you don't know what firebug is go to http://getfirebug.com/ , install this to your firefox for example, and go to the Net bar, then click on your button which is supposed to trigger the ajax call, and see if you see your request on the Net tab in firebug, if you don't, you have some JS issues, otherwise the problem might be coming from php

can you put your code on jsFiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()){   
   return new Response(json_encode(array(
      'form'=>$this->render('mainBundle:Register:register.html.twig')->getContent()))
   );
}
```